# Interaction representation time evolution operator

Tags: time-evolution

I saw that in the interaction representation, the time evolution operator is $$\hat{U}(t) = e^{iH_0 t}e^{-iHt} $$
where $H$ can be expressed as $H=H_0 + V$, so is it possible to simply write it as $e^{-iVt}$? Or is this not possible, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. The equation 
$$ e^{iH_0t}e^{-iHt}=e^{-iVt}$$
is true only if $[H_0, V]=0$, which is not the general case, and certainly not the interesting case.

For the rules of combining exponents of operators, you can also read about the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula).